# How to make the COM host process avoid inheriting the environment variables from the parent process

Tags: c++, winapi, environment-variables

My OS is Win7 x64. I have two exe named ComHost.exe and ClientApp.exe.

The ComHost.exe is a standalone exe and also a the COM host for the out-of-process COM.

ClientApp.exe creates the COM instance by calling the CoCreateInstance(...). When create the COM instance, the process ComHost.exe starts.

In the windows environment variables, there is a variable "AppStatus=status1".

In the implementation of ClientApp.exe, the code is like that

```
int ret = putenv("AppStatus=status2"); // Change the environment variable.
// do something
CoCreateInstance(...); // Start ComHost.exe
```

In the implementation of ComHost.exe, I get the viriable value with the code

```
char * pStatus = getenv("AppStatus");
```

**Case 1**: If start the ComHost.exe by double click it, the value of pStatus is "status1".

**Case 2**: If start the ComHost.exe in ClientApp.exe, the value of pStatus is "status2". It inherits the environment variables of the *parent* process ClientApp.exe.

My question is:

I want ComHost.exe always reads the variable value defined by OS not the value inherited from  the *parent* process. That means, in case 2, I want to get the value "status1". Is it possible?

Comment: Possible, certainly. I think you're on the wrong track here using an environment variable to communicate a status -- first of all, you are polluting all applications with your status, and second, you cannot update the status once the host process is running.

Comment: I take the variable AppStatus as example is to make the thing easy to be understood.

Comment: My point still stands -- most likely using an environment variable is not the solution. Very often, questions posted here have been partitioned into an easy and a hard (or impossible) part, the latter being asked, while looking at the entire problem would tell us that the first part of the solution is actually the wrong way.

Comment: The environment value issue in my realistic project is the variable PATH. In ClientApp.exe, the PATH is changed. And in ComHost.exe, it will call API ::LoadLibrary("somedll.dll"); to load the dll. LoadLibrary depends on the value of PATH. It will fails in this case (The PATH is changed by 'parent' ClientApp.exe). Worse, the ClientApp.exe is started by another exe. So the environment variable is changed and propagated serveral times. To make sure the ComHost.exe can load the dll correctly, it needs to use the correct PATH when start the ComHost.exe.

Comment: I see. Can you somehow find the DLL's absolute path (e.g. by querying the registry), so you can pass the full path to `LoadLibrary`?

Comment: Well, an obvious workaround is to change it *back* just before you create the first object.  Depending on PATH to find DLLs is however always a bad idea.  Consider SetDllDirectory() or keeping DLLs in the same directory as the EXE.

Comment: @Simon. That's impossible for my case. ComHost.exe is a third party product. We only consume it by the COM interface but can't change its source code. I have the source code of ClientApp.exe. I can add the fix to it. I will have a try the workaround from Hans. Read the path value from registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path, and set PATH with the API putenv(), then call CoCreateInstance() to start the ComHost.exe. After the process is started, recover the PTAH.

Comment: That is probably the best solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you double-click the "ComHost.exe" process, you're probably doing so from Explorer.EXE. That means you don't get the "variable value defined by OS". You just inherit it from Explorer.EXE (which, admittably, is started in a special way during login.)

Behind the scenes, we're always using `CreateProcess` or a variant thereof. Its default behavior it to create a new process, copying the environment variables of the calling process. As you're not in charge of creating that new process (in case 2, COM is), you can't alter this behavior.

So, therefore, in both cases, `getenv` will get you the inherited value, and in case 2 you cannot get the value "that you would have inherited from Explorer.EXE".

Comment: The value inherited from Explorer.EXE is saved in the registry. I think I can try the workaround to set the variable by the value from registry, then call the CoCreateInstance(...); to start ComHost.exe.